# Including a .txt file in an APK

Tags: android, gradle

I am generating a signed APK using Gradle and all is good. What I am trying to achieve is to place a .txt file into the bundle's root. I've tried various examples like `com.github.hierynomus.license plugin` or `sourceSets` but none I could make it. The APK's contents:

```
> lib
> META-INF
> res
> AndroidManifest.xml
> here.txt
```

I can unzip and place the file manually but it breaks the signature. How can I add a custom file into my generated APK?

Thanks!

Comment: "What I am trying to achieve is to place a .txt file into the bundle's root" -- why? That is rather unusual.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's an app to be used internally for a company which will not be placed in the store. The server should be able to check the file version through the .txt file it contains. You'd probably suggest using aapt but that's not installed in the server side. I thought this to be the simplest workaround. Or is it not?

Comment: If you can name the APK file arbitrarily, and can be reasonably confident it won't be changed, you could just put the version number in the file name.

Comment: Why would the file have to be in the root directory? Package it as a regular asset (in `app/src/main/assets/` for an `app/` module).

Comment: @nasch That will definitely not work and might open a gate to a huge mess. :-/

Comment: @CommonsWare That'd work as well. It's just that to access to the root path is relatively easier and solid as (maybe) source path may be changed in time. I can perform a simple file search as well so it doesn't really matter where it is located as long as it is.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've tried to place the text file in Android Studio under the **resources** folder but it was not there in the generated APK file.

Comment: There is no `resources` folder in a standard Android app project. I suggested putting the file as an asset (in `app/src/main/assets/` for an `app/` module). That will put the file in an `assets/` directory inside of the APK.

Comment: @CommonsWare I salute you Murphy. That did the trick.

Comment: Why don't you add it to assets directory?